# Getx oninit dont replace values - Geolocator

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, geolocator

I was testing a code on my Android device but in the replacement part of the code in the terminal it prints the previous values and not the values changed in the getPosition().

**CODE WITH GEOLOCATOR**

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';

class GlobalController extends GetxController {
//variables
  final RxBool _isloading = true.obs;
  final RxDouble _latitud = 0.0.obs;
  final RxDouble _longitud = 0.0.obs;
  RxBool checkLoading() => _isloading;
  RxDouble getLatitude() => _latitud;
  RxDouble getlongitude() => _longitud;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    getLocation();
    super.onInit();
  }

  getLocation() async {
    bool isServiceEnabled;
    LocationPermission locationPermission;
    isServiceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!isServiceEnabled) {
      return Future.error("GPS no disponible");
    }

    locationPermission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

    if (locationPermission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error("La aplicación nunca tendrá los permisos");
    } else if (locationPermission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      locationPermission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (locationPermission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error("La aplicación no tiene los permisos");
      }
    }

    return Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((value) => {
              _latitud.value = value.longitude,
              _longitud.value = value.longitude,
              _isloading.value = false
            });
  }
}
```

**widget where I call geolocator**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../controller/global_controller.dart';

class HeaderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const HeaderWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<HeaderWidget> createState() => _HeaderWidgetState();
}

class _HeaderWidgetState extends State<HeaderWidget> {
  String city = "Hola Mundo";
  final GlobalController globalController =
      Get.put(GlobalController(), permanent: true);
  @override
  void initState() {
    getAddress();
    super.initState();
  }

  getAddress() async {
    double value = GlobalController().getLatitude().value;
    city = "Reemplazado";
    print(value);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Text(city),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

At the beginning I thought that it could be an error in the last return, so I changed the values at the beginning of the class and it still did not change. Similar when I changed the values in onInit()

Comment: Sorry if I have wasted your valuable time. The problem was a bad call of the variable "geolocator", I was calling the Geolocator function, but not the const geolocator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After assigning the value, refresh the variables

```
    return Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
    .then((value) => {
          _latitud.value = value.longitude,
          _longitud.value = value.longitude,
          _isloading.value = false

          //<<---Try adding this--->>
          _latitud.refresh(),
          _longitud.refresh(),
          _isloading.refresh(),
        });
```

Comment: Nothing. I tried changing the initial value of _latitude, _longitude to see if the print sent 0.0 by the refresh() but it still sends me the initial value.